# How can I run classes that have the same name as java standard classes?

Tags: java, classloader

I am trying to run some code that uses classes that have the same name as the ones in the `javax.xml.crypto` packages. But I seem to be running the system classes instead.

I have only managed to run the code with the flag:

```
java -Xbootclasspath/p:</path/to/classes> -cp:</path/to/classes> <main.Class>
```

But I really want to avoid touching the bootstrap classloader. Is there another way?

Comment: Are only the classnames the same or are they also in the same package?

Comment: @ErikEkman they also in the same package.

Comment: In general, classes that correspond to one of the JDK package names must be loaded from the boot classpath.  There is (quite by design, for security) no way to place stuff ahead of the boot class path other than by modifying the `java` command as you demonstrate.

Comment: @HotLicks That makes sense. But I am actually able to run them with the JUnit plugin in Eclipse. I have added some prints to the code and they show up so I know that the classes are being executed.

Comment: Can you create a custom classloader which does not use parent classes, and loads your custom version from its custom class path?

Comment: Eclipse plays its own games with the classpaths.